# Output from Word2Vec

Tags: word2vec

I am working on sentiment analysis. I am using Word2Vec method. I don't understand the output from this code line.

```
 dum_out =  Word2Vec(size = 200,min_count = 10, window = 5 )
```

It gives a vector of 200 dimensions for each word(let us take a word "break"). So `dum_out['break']` gives me a vector of 200 dimensions. I  I understand that these numbers in the vector are probabilities of how close 'break' is to 'other words' . But my question is what are these 'other words' ? With what context are these figures calculated ? How does the 'dimensions' parameter affect the model ?
(You can consider any vocabulary size if needed and any other parameters accordingly)

Answer (score 2):

The numbers inside the vector are not probabilities. Indeed, they are not bounded between 0 and 1. Each number is just a real number, and the whole vector represents the embedding for a given word. To find the similarity between two words you are supposed to compute the cosine similarity (again, not a probability).

The way those numbers are computed depends on the implementation: common algorithms are SkipGram and CBOW. Basically a single layer neural network is trained to predict a word given some context (the size of the context is controlled by the `window` parameter) words (or vice versa), and after some epochs the layer provides word embeddings, that is vector representations of the words.

If you increase the value of the `size` parameter, you obtain a richer embedding for each word.

However, it looks like you are trying to do something without having a clue about what you are really doing. There is plenty of articles explaining word2vec, take a look at one of them: https://skymind.ai/wiki/word2vec